# How to control computer through iPod

Tags: remote-desktop, ipod

I have enabled the setting that allows people who connect to my computer to control it. Now, I was wondering if there was a way to connect to it through my iPod and control it from there?

If so, do you guy's reccomend any apps? Also, where do I find the info on how to connect to my computer?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't use any Apple products, so I can't recommend a good app, but you are looking for is a VNC client. Hopefully this will at least point you in the right direction, if no one answers.

Comment: What was that setting? Because to my knowledge in order to remotely connect to a computer you user SSH. Check to see if there are some SSH clients for your iOS based device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search the app store for the keyword "VNC client" as mentioned in the comments.
Or you can install teamviewer on your ipod and computer.
This would have the advantage that you don't need to change any port forwarding, firewall or other security settings on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [splashtop](http://www.splashtop.com/home). it is really fast and you can be 10 miles away and still control it.

Comment: This does not answer the question because Splashtop does support remote connections from an iPod.